# CSR generating code breaks after upgrading openssl

Tags: c, openssl, upgrade, signing, csr

We have existing code that generates a CSR as follows:

```
void create_csr()
{
    EVP_PKEY * pk = EVP_PKEY_new();
    RSA * rsa = RSA_generate_key(RSA_SIZE, RSA_F4, NULL, NULL);
    EVP_PKEY_set1_RSA(pk, rsa);
    X509_REQ * x = X509_REQ_new();
    X509_REQ_set_pubkey(x, pk);

    BIO * outBio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    PEM_write_bio_X509_REQ(outBio, x)
    char * buf;
    size_t bufLen = BIO_get_mem_data(outBio, &buf);
    WriteToFile(buf, bufLen, "cert_req.csr"); // <== File IO details inside
}
```

Running `# openssl asn1parse -in cert_req.csr`

With `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`:

```sh
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 312 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 300 cons: SEQUENCE          
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: INTEGER           :00
   10:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 cons: SEQUENCE          
   12:d=2  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE          
   16:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
   18:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   29:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   31:d=3  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING        
  306:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
  308:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 cons: SEQUENCE          
  310:d=2  hl=2 l=   1 prim: OBJECT            :itu-t
  313:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: BIT STRING
```

With `OpenSSL 1.1.1b 26 Feb 2019`:

```sh
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 310 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 301 cons: SEQUENCE          
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
   11:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 cons: SEQUENCE          
   13:d=2  hl=4 l= 290 cons: SEQUENCE          
   17:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
   19:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   30:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
   32:d=3  hl=4 l= 271 prim: BIT STRING        
  307:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
  309:d=1  hl=2 l=   0 cons: SEQUENCE          
  311:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: BIT STRING
```

It seems that with `OpenSSL 1.1.1b 26 Feb 2019`, the `prim: OBJECT :itu-t` field is omitted.

Trying to use the `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013` shell command to read the CSR made with `OpenSSL 1.1.1b 26 Feb 2019` fails as follows:

```sh
# openssl req -in cert_req.csr -pubkey -noout -outform pem 
unable to load X509 request
140324106245960:error:0D078079:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:field missing:tasn_dec.c:526:Field=algorithm, Type=X509_ALGOR
140324106245960:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:777:Field=sig_alg, Type=X509_REQ
140324106245960:error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib:pem_oth.c:83:
```

Our `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013` based server fails to parse the CSR and generate a certificate

**FOCUSING THE QUESTION**: is there a way to make `OpenSSL 1.1.1b 26 Feb 2019` use `itu-t` as the signature algorithm, and insert a `prim: OBJECT :itu-t` field and value into the ASN.1 encoding, when generating the CSR? How?

Many thanks!

Comment: **You didn't sign it.** Both the signatureAlgorithm field AND the signature (value) field are filled in by `X509_REQ_sign`. The `OBJECT itu-t` you were getting before is actually a bogus decoding of an invalid OID.

Comment: Indeed our existing flow doesn't sign it. But is there a way to recreate this bogus OID decoding?

Comment: (1) Use 1.0.1 or lower (2) calling `OBJ_create` for 0.0 and breaking encapsulation to inject it into sigalg should encode the bogus value but by default 1.0.2 up will decode as 0.0; also setting the name(s) and calling `OBJ_add_object` _may_ fix that (not tested) (2) fork/build your own version patching the data-gen process for OBJ to recreate the bugs and make at least NID_undef (#0) and NID_itu_t (#645) use value `0x00`; I can't tell if any others are needed, or if this will break any other things (3) don't do it (or at least not using OpenSSL)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thanks for the advise. What did eventually was to sign the CSR properly by openssl 1.1.1b. After that, the server side had to be adjusted to generate the certificate properly, so openssl 1.1.1b would accept it.